# Randomize 2 resource parameters the same way into an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, random

I have a resource named `stream` and it has parameters `video_id` and `length`. Each `video_id` has a corresponding `length`.

I want to create two arrays, one that stores all the `video_id`'s and one that stores all the `length`'s. I want to randomize the `video_id` array but sort the lengths array so that its indices correspond to the correct `video_id`'s in the randomized array.

I could obtain the `video_id` array with

```
ids = Stream.friendly.find(params[:id]).videos.pluck(:video_id).shuffle
```

How do I get the correct `length` array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure the best way to get the lengths using the method of getting shuffled ids that you've outlined, but using `transpose` will help you out greatly.

```
ids, lengths = Stream.friendly.find(params[:id]).videos.pluck(:video_id, :length).shuffle.transpose
```

`ids` will be set to exactly what you had before (well, shuffled of course), and `lengths` will be set to the `ids` corresponding `length`, in order.